# imprimir con php

Tags: php

tengo este codigo:

```
foreach($this->table_descriptor->getColumns() as $column){
  $buf .= "\t\t$this->$".$column['Field']." = NULL,\n";
}
```

lo que deberia imprimir:

```
$this->Columna = NULL,
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_CHARACTER, expecting T_STRING in
```

alguna sugerencia? gracias!

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis. Usa `'\t\t$this->$'` o bien `"\t\t$this->\$"`. El carácter `$` es un carácter especial y trata de interpretar el valor de una variable cuando se usan comillas dobles. Si insistes en usar comillas dobles tendrás que escapar el carácter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes escapar los caracteres $ a \$ tanto el `$this` a `\$this` como el de delante de la variable. son los que te están dando ese error.

Comment: gracias! por la ayuda!